# How to give .txt filepath in c# to c++.dll file

Tags: c#, c++

I have main program in c++ like this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
char *strFileName = "input.txt";

ifstream inFile; //Input file
ofstream outFile; //Outut file
vector<string> line; //Vector holding lines

inFile.open(strFileName); //Opens file
outFile.open("output.txt");
string wordLine;

while (getline(inFile,wordLine))
{
line.push_back(wordLine);
outfile<<wordLine<<endl;
}

inFile.close(); //Close the input file

return 0;
}
```

I want to create a .dll file such that i can browse (input.txt) file path in C# GUI and insert in place of strFileName in c++.

In the same way by clicking the button it has to open the (output.txt).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: @t3chb0t --- I tried an example on mathematical functions like this
    extern "C" {__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a,int b) { return a+b; } 
and created .dll file. But, i dont know how to write for this.

Answer (score 0):

Exchanging such data is not trivial because C# runs on the [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) and therefore you can not pass e.g. a `String` or other data as simple as you can pass parameters to a C++ function inside a C++ program.

What you are might looking for is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). You'll have to write C++/CLI wrappers for the C# calls.

```
C++    |   C++/CLI    |  C#
        <------------>
```

Where C++/CLI works as an interface wrapper between your C++ and your C# program.

One could also use sockets and transmit raw binary data or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data (see [Marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29)) via localhost. But it depends on how you want to design your program architecture and which technologies you want to use (and which not).

Comment: This should be a comment. I think @AbdulArif wants us to write the whole winforms application.

Comment: @t3chb0t I added a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**In C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C"  
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int mainfun(char* strpath)
    {
        ifstream inFile; //Input file
        ofstream outFile; //Outut file
        vector<string> line; //Vector holding lines

        string tmppath(strpath);
        inFile.open(tmppath); //Opens file

        outFile.open("OutPut.txt");     //****Command to write file ****//

        while (getline(inFile,wordLine))
        {
           line.push_back(wordLine);
           outFile<<wordLine<<endl;
        }

        inFile.close(); //Close the input file
        outFile.close(); //Close the output file

        return 0;
     }
}
```

**In C# Form**

```
[DllImport("ascii_project.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int mainfun(string strpath)

string filepath;

OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

private void browsebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofd.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt*";   //Filter
    ofd.InitialDirectory = @"c:\Desktop\";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)    //If browse Button was pressed
    {
        filepath = ofd.FileName;
    }
    mainfun(filepath);
}
```